# Search DOM selector for a match to values in array; return matched value

Tags: javascript

I need to pull the text content from a DOM selector, that contains delivery information, including country name, which I need to put in a variable.

I have a list of the possible countries:

```
var countries = [
    "France",
    "Denmark",
    "Finland"
];
```

And the DOM selector:

```
var dom_Selector = document.querySelector("#primary > div > table.Order > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(1)");
```

Here is a sample of the HTML content of this td-element:

```
<br>Firstname Lastname<br>Street name<br>Postalcode City<br>Country<br><br>Leveres til:<br>Pickup location<br>Firstname Lastname<br>Street name<br>Postal code and city<br>Country<br>
```

So the challenge is that the selector doesnt wrap the country string; therefore the entire contents of the selector needs to be searched.

If there is a match to the array of countries, I then need to return which country is matched.

Then there is a second step, which is that I need to match the country name to a country code; e.g. France -> FR, Denmark -> DK, Finland -> FI.

So the result from the text content of the selector will be for instance "FI" - a country code. And this needs to be put in a variable.

Comment: with the querySelector you will get a node. How exactly you want a node to match a string? Does the node have a class that references to each country?

Comment: No - that is a mistake. I need the HTML/text content of that DOM element to be put into a object.

Comment: Can you please insert some html code too?

Comment: The HTML simply consists of a td-element with some line breaks (<br>) and delivery information. As such:
<td><br>Firstname Lastname<br>Street name<br>Postalcode City<br>Country<br><br>Leveres til:<br>Pickup location<br>Firstname Lastname<br>Street name<br>Postal code and city<br>Country<br></td>

Comment: @nddk You should have added those HTML details to your question. Anyway, I've already answer, and I think it fits your need.

Comment: @nddk I added the answer .

Comment: @nddk Chekc my answer again. I updated it according to your question

Comment: @AnastasiosSelmanis Thanks a lot Anastasios - I will review your solution tonight! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelector` returns only the first element within the document that matches the specified selector. IF you want to iterate over all the elements that could match the selector you need to use `querySelectorAll`

```js
const selector = document.querySelectorAll('.container .country');
let countries = [];
selector.forEach((node) => {
  countries.push(node.innerText);
});

console.log(countries);
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="country">France</span>
  <span class="country">Spain</span>
  <span class="country">Germany</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you want to do,
I suggest you to to that kind of things:
(See snippet for working example, and comments in the code)

```js
var countries = [
  "France",
  "Denmark",
  "Finland"
];

// Example of code only for 1 element
console.log("Result for a querySelector:");
var dom_Selector = document.querySelector("body > div.content.Delivery_TD");
// The query selector above will return only the first matching element
countries.forEach(function(val) {
  if (dom_Selector.innerHTML.includes(val)) {
    console.log(val, ": found!");
  }
});

// For multiple elements
console.log("Results for a querySelectorAll:");
var dom_Selector = document.querySelectorAll("body > div.content.Delivery_TD");
// The query selector above will return all the matching elements
dom_Selector.forEach(function(elm) {
  countries.forEach(function(val) {
    if (elm.innerHTML.includes(val)) {
      console.log(val, ": found!");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body>div.content.Delivery_TD {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 4px 8px;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="content Delivery_TD">
    Delivery from France the 05/03/2018 at 09:50PM
  </div>
  <div class="content Delivery_TD">
    Delivery from Finland the 05/06/2018 at 11:50AM
  </div>
  <div class="content Delivery_TD">
    Delivery from Denmark the 05/04/2018 at 06:20PM
  </div>

</body>
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use `querySelectorAll` method instead of `querySelector`.

```js
var countries = [];

document.querySelectorAll(".content .Delivery_TD").forEach(function(itm) {
  countries.push(itm.textContent);
});

console.log(countries);
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="Delivery_TD"> C1 </div>
  <div class="Delivery_TD"> C2 </div>
  <div class="Delivery_TD"> C3 </div>
  <div class="Delivery_TD"> C4 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE**
First of all you want your array of countries to be associative in order to have the information of the key (FR, FN etc)

Something like that

```
var countries = {
  "FR": "France", 
  "DN": "Denmark",
  "FN": "Finland" 
}
```

Then you can find the code from the country inside the string like that

```
var dom_Selector = ..... Your selector
var dom_Selector_text = dom_Selector.textContent;
// or
// var dom_Selector_text = dom_Selector.firstChild.nodeValue;

var result = "";

for (var key in countries) {
    if(dom_Selector_text.indexOf(countries[key]) !== -1){
        result = key;
  }
}

return result
```

Comment: But this returns the entire text, not just the matched value, right?

Comment: @nddk If the value exists in the list of countries it will return the value. The name of the country. What do you mean with the value? The index of the array that matches the text? Is that what you want?

Comment: Doesnt "return dom_Selector_text;" simply return the entire content of dom_Selector.textContent; ?

Comment: The index of the array would be useful as well. Because there is a second step, where I need to match the country name to a country code - e.g. France needs to be matched to the country code FR, which I guess would be best done with an index of the array

Comment: Why you check the index of the array and stuff like that when you can iterate over all the nodes that return the query? Check my answer!

Comment: Cristian S.: the country string is not in its own node, but is inside a table element with lots of other text and linebreaks.

Comment: @nddk add please your html code inside your question and write down the entire case. What should be returned and what do you want to get. Your write in your questions that the selector is what you say. If the selector doesn't wrap the country string how exactly are we suppose to understand the structure of your DOM. An don't write html in the comments. Nobody wants to help a guy that doesn't want to help himself to make his question more clear.

Comment: Anastasios: You are right; I will be sure to be more accurate in my descriptions in the future.

Comment: @AnastasiosSelmanis - I have hereby expanded upon and clarified the original post, detailing the problem at hand.

Comment: @CristianS. I don't think you have understood the question. He doesn't want to get the list out of the DOM elements. He want to see inside the dom elements if there is a country matched from his existing array.